# Calculating a text as a hex

Tags: c#

I want to receive a hex calculating on:

```
  static int count = 0;
  string s;
  private void SetClock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        count++;
        label5.Text = count.ToString("X2");
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        s = "4D-" + "1A-" + "2B-" + "3C-" +(label5.Text);
        txtSend.Text = s;
   }
```

After that i remove the '-' between the code and i want to add the HEX calculated result after "(label5.text)":

4D 1A 2B 3C (label5.text) (hex result on (4D 1A 2B 3C (label5.text))).

I can't understand how to tell my program to get different bytes - 4D/1A/2B... This is actually what we can do with the calculator on Scientific Mode selected "hex function" and typing all those 4D 1A.. by pressing XOR.

Comment: I didn't get the question. You mean you want to have a textbox which gets hex string as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand Correctly, You want to apply `XOR` on your `s` value and store its result in `HEX` in to `txtSend.Text` If so you can try this

```
s = "4D-" + "1A-" + "2B-" + "3C-" +(label5.Text);
string [] allHaxValues= s.Split(new char[]{'-'});
int result = 0;

foreach(string haxValue in allHaxValues)
{
   result = result ^ Convert.ToInt32(haxValue, 16);
}
txtSend.Text = result.ToString("X");
```

IF `label5.Text` Contains `1` then result will be `41`

like

```
result = 4D XOR 1A XOR 2B XOR 3C XOR 1
```

Comment: @NikolaObretenov No Need to declare s as var in your method.

Comment: it gives me error: Type and indentifier are both required in a foreach statement. The error is linked on "in" here: "foreach(var haxValue in allHaxValues)"

Comment: @NikolaObretenov, Try with foreach(string haxValue in allHaxValues)

Comment: @NikolaObretenov, Answer is updated, Check it now, hope it will help

Comment: I dont get error now, but i don't see the result next to 4D 1A 2B 3C ... i need to see it as a result next to label's text. As you said if label5.text = 1 we need to see: 4D-1A-2B-3C-01-result

Comment: @NikolaObretenov, Do you want the result in txtSend  TextBox like `4D-1A-2B-3C-01 Result 41`. Or Something other can you paste any illustration in your question.

Comment: Thank you Yograj Gupta!
Greetings!
Obretenov :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is might be what you were looking for, note that I have Replaced `'-'` with `' '` so you can use this in your code.

```
count++;
label5.Text = count.ToString("X2");
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
s = "4D-" + "1A-" + "2B-" + "3C-" + label5.Text;
s = s.Replace('-', ' ');
string[] strings = s.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
List<int> ints = strings.Select(a => int.Parse(a,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)).ToList<int>();
int xor = ints[0];
for(int i=1;i<ints.Count;i++)
{
      xor ^= ints[i];
}
txtSend.Text = s + " (" + xor.ToString("X2") + ")";
```

Comment: Nick i think your code will work too, but I already get it by Yograj :) Thanks you too

Comment: @NikolaObretenov It's OK, the most important is that you solved your problem ;-)